# Power BI data refresh - deleted columns in Excel still present as Fields

Tags: excel, powerbi, field, refresh

I have a simple Power BI dashboard which links to just one spreadsheet.  The spreadsheet contains superfluous Columns, which I have now deleted.
However, when I refresh the data in Power BI, the Fields which were created from those Columns still exist on the right hand side.
How do I get Power BI to recognise that those Columns / Fields no longer exist?
I can delete them manually but I would expect there to be a sleeker option.
Thanks

Comment: Go to power query editor and open the table in Advance Query Editor mode. Remove all deleted columns from their and refresh everything.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the "Transform Data" icon and you will end up in the PowerQuery designer (which is where you are deleting the columns). First refresh your preview (the circled option below).

If that does not work, then right click your table and select advanced editor.

Remove the columns from the Transform

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another reason can be when you've deleted a column you have previously renamed. This triggers an identical error as there's nothing to be renamed.
Its just a different type of error and thus different line in Murray Foxcroft's reply.
Solution: Avoid the field to be part of any logical expression in "Advanced Editor" view.