# Refreshing Power BI data source from an Excel file where one column has been deleted

Tags: powerbi, refresh

I have a Power BI dashboard published to the Power BI cloud service which is fed from an Excel file in Sharepoint online. The scheduled refresh has recently started failing. An unused column from the Excel file was deleted. That column is not used in the dashboard.

Power BI doesn't seem to realize that the column has been deleted. How can I refresh the semantic model's schema?

Many other answers online involve downloading the PBIX file and editing the steps in Power Query ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63918624/power-bi-data-refresh-deleted-columns-in-excel-still-present-as-fields)). I can only download this file with a live connection to the online data, which prevents me from using Power Query here. Additionally, I've tried refreshing the PBIX file and it fails, just like the scheduled refresh.

Comment: You don't have access to the original PBIX? Ultimately you will need to update PowerQuery (it most likely has a `Changed Type` step on all the columns). To download the PBIX, go to the workspace where the dataset is. Click on the `...` next to the dataset, and select `Download this file`.

Comment: I take it that the report is a front end to another report that holds the dataset that gets the data? you'll have to download that original connection to update the power query

Comment: @SamNseir You should post that as an answer. I hadn't considered downloading a PBIX file for the data source. That didn't appear in the other questions/answers I checked out. Turns out that was the answer.